# Como usar Herança de templates, para herdar Folhas de Estilo (css) no meu projeto Django?

Tags: html, css, django

Tenho uma template base.html e outra template library.html que esta herdando base!
Consegui herdar a maior parte de base.html, só que quando tento adicionar mais uma tag link no bloco de Estilo O Django acusa erro de TemplateSyntaxError, quando eu retiro o bloco com a nova tag link a mais ele renderiza a template normalmente!

### Base.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% load staticfiles %}
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="author" content="">
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="">

<title>{% block title %}{% endblock %}</title>

<link href="{% static 'css/bootstrap.min.css ' %}" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="{% static 'css/starter-template.css ' %}" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="{% static 'css/navbar-static-top.css ' %}" rel="stylesheet">

{% block Estilo %}
{% endblock %}

</head>

<body>

<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Library Chameleon</a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#emprestimo">Emprestimo</a></li>
        <li><a href="#relatorios">Relatórios</a></li>

        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Serviços <b class="caret"></b></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#cadLivros">Cadastrar Livros</a></li>
            <li><a href="#cadUsuarios">Cadastrar Usuarios</a></li>
            <li><a href="#cadFuncionarios">Cadastrar Funcionarios</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li class="dropdown-header">Pesquisa</li>
            <li><a href="#pesqLivro">Livro</a></li>
            <li><a href="#pesqUsuario">Usuario</a></li>
            <li><a href="#pesqFuncionario">Funcionario</a></li>
          </ul>
         </li>

      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

{% block Corpo %}
{% endblock %}

<!-- JavaScript
================================================== -->

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="{% static 'js/bootstrap.min.js ' %}"></script>
{% block JScript %}
{% endblock %}
```

### Library.html:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block title %}Chameleon | Cadastro de Livro{% endblock %}

{% block Estilo %}
<link href="{% static 'css/cadastros.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
{% endblock %}

{% block Corpo %}       
<div class="container">

  <form class="form-signin" role="form">
    <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Cadastro</h2>

    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="codigo" name= "codigo" placeholder="Codigo" required autofocus>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="titulo" name= "titulo" placeholder="Titulo" required>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="autor" name= "autor" placeholder="Autor" required>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="editora" name= "editora" placeholder="Editora" required>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="genero" name= "genero" placeholder="Genero" required>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="publicacao" name= "publicacao" placeholder="Ano: 0000" required>

    <textarea id="sinopse" name="sinopse" placeholder="Sinopse" rows = 10 cols = 63 required></textarea>

    <br><button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Salvar</button>
  </form>
</div>
{% endblock %}

{% block JScript %}
{% endblock %}
```

### Erro retornado do Django:

```
TemplateSyntaxError at /cadLivro/
Invalid block tag: 'static', expected 'endblock'
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/cadLivro/
Django Version: 1.6.2
Exception Type: TemplateSyntaxError
Exception Value:    
Invalid block tag: 'static', expected 'endblock'
Exception Location: C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py in invalid_block_tag, line 331
Python Executable:  C:\Python27\python.exe
Python Version: 2.7.6
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adicione o `{% load staticfiles %}` no `library.html` também.

No Django é obrigatório adicionar os cabeçalhos necessários em cada arquivo de template, mesmo que eles já estejam declarados no  template-base. Você está usando o `static` dentro do bloco de estilo, mas o template ainda não sabe o que isso significa, devido a ausência do `{% load staticfiles %}`.